# How to create a stored procedure in POSTGRESQL that makes a FOR loop?

Tags: sql, postgresql, for-loop, stored-procedures, triggers

I am studying how to create triggers and stored procedures in POSTGRESQL and I have the task to update a column called num_long_title_songs of table ALBUM.

It is needed to count the number of songs with more than 12 characters on a table called songs and then update the value of the column in ALBUM.

I have created the next querie with a for loop, that does exactly what I want:

```
do $$
begin
    FOR i IN 1..100 LOOP
    UPDATE ALBUM
    SET  num_long_title_songs =(SELECT count(s.title)
                                FROM ALBUM a,SONG s
                                WHERE a.id_album=s.id_album
                                AND LENGTH(s.title) > 12
                                AND a.id_album=i
                                GROUP BY a.id_album
                                ORDER BY a.id_album)
    WHERE id_album IN (SELECT a.id_album
                                FROM ALBUM a,SONG s
                                WHERE a.id_album=s.id_album
                                AND LENGTH(s.title) > 12
                                AND a.id_album=i
                                GROUP BY a.id_album
                                ORDER BY a.id_album);
    -- i will take on the values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 within the loop
    END LOOP;
END; $$
```

The problem is that i need to create a stored procedure in order to make a trigger. I tried puting this inside the CREATE FUNCTION structure but I cant create it... could you help me in getting to know how to put this 'for' loop inside a function?

Comment: You don't need a loop. You don't need a function. You don't need a trigger. [and you should use the `JOIN` syntax]

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, instead of the comma-separated list of tables from 1989.

Comment: @wildplasser I DO need a trigger and a function but for the next steps I think I couldn't explain correctly the exercise. I wanted to know how to put the for inside the function, to later use it in the triggers :c Thanks for the suggestion about the Join I'll check it :D

Comment: @TheImpaler I will use them  :D thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the existing rows in table ALBUM, you just have to run the following `UPDATE` statement :

```
UPDATE ALBUM a
   SET num_long_title_songs = s.total
FROM ( SELECT s.id_album
            , count(s.title) AS total
         FROM SONG s
        WHERE LENGTH(s.title) > 12
        GROUP BY s.id_album
     ) AS s
WHERE a.id_album=s.id_album
  AND a.num_long_title_songs <> s.total ;
```

If you want to automatically update the *num_long_title_songs* field of table `ALBUM` when a row is inserted or updated in table `SONG`, then you need a `trigger function` :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_num_long_title_songs ()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE ALBUM a
       SET num_long_title_songs = s.total
    FROM ( SELECT s.id_album
                , count(s.title) AS total
             FROM SONG s
            WHERE LENGTH(s.title) > 12
              AND s.id_album = NEW.id_album
         ) AS s
    WHERE a.id_album=s.id_album
      AND a.num_long_title_songs <> s.total ;
END ;
$$ ;
    
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_update_SONG AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF title ON SONG
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION update_num_long_title_songs () ;
```

AFTER is important so that to take into account the new row inserted or updated in table `SONG` for the new value of the *num_long_title_songs*.

Comment: Absolutely, the `UPDATE OF title` clause in the trigger declaration was a first level of preventive medicine, and this `WHERE ` condition definitively prevents from any risk. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: @EdouardH. Thanks for your help it was very useful. I was approaching the problem in a very "python loop" way of thinking :D